# JavaFX (8) equivalent for JGoodies' FormLayout or WindowBuilder's AbsoluteLayout

Tags: user-interface, javafx-8

Coming from Swing applications I am used to use JGoodies 'FormLayout' or WindowBuilder's 'AbsoluteLayout' to create UI forms.

Is there any equivalent to either in JavaFX (8)?

Comment: `Pane` and `GridPane`???

Answer (score 0):

The JGoodies FormLayout is available for JavaFX too.

Comment: Please expand your answer. How can we us jGoodies in JavaFx. Post a code sample maybe.  Post a link to the JavaFX version maybe.

Answer (score 0):

And there also is http://miglayout.com/ which one might consider similar to JGoodies FormLayout.